# Similar tool like pulse picker to decrease rep. freq. of pulsed laser?

Tags: optics, laser

Now the laser I'm using is with 100MHz repetition frequency. For some measurement, I need to decrease to 20MHz (or 40MHz, 60MHz, between 10MHz to 60MHz is good). Apart from pulse picker, is there any other technique to realize?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about how much access you have to the actual laser, what type of laser you're using, or what type of measurement you're doing, it's difficult to suggest alternative solutions to pulse pickers, but there are several options to change the repetition rate of a pulsed laser (also depending on the technology used for pulsing, but based on your repetition rate of 100MHz I'm guessing you have either a solid-state mode-locked laser or a gain-switched semiconductor laser):

- The cavity length dictates the repetition rate of mode-locked lasers. So if you have access to the cavity you could adjust the repetition rate that way, although the reasonably achievable range of repetition rates will be far below the kind of range you're looking for.
- If you have a gain-switched semiconductor laser, it might be possible to change the repetition rate via your laser drive current, but this will depend on the model of your laser and your laser driver (current source). Maybe the user manual or the manufacturer will have further information on your options there.
- If you don't want to use a pulse picker, maybe you can change the rep rate of your measurement, e.g. via the acquisition rate of your detector?